# Javascript setTimeOut fires any way when i load new section with ajax

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Javascript setTimeOut fires any way when i load new section with ajax. I wrote up a javascript function to check if the page is idle for 5 seconds then hide header and bottom nav of my page. During the page load proccess i clicked the new tab to load new content. What happens when new section is loaded through jQuery it fires the previouse timeOut function. I am stuck with it.
Here is my code of wait and load new section

Wait code check idle state:

```
function checkIdleHome() {

    //check the idle if no event occured
    if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||  (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {

        var events = ['ontouchstart','ontouchend','ontouchmove'],
                i = events.length,
            timer,
            delay = 5000,
            logout = function () {
            // do whatever it is you want to do
            // after a period of inactivity
            //alert('lazy boy');
            //alert('i am fired');
            if(document.getElementById('mainnav')) {
                        document.getElementById('mainnav').style.display='none';        
            }
            if(document.getElementById('header')) {                             
                        document.getElementById('header').style.display='none';     
            }
                },
                reset = function () {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(logout, delay);
        //alert(timer);
        };

            while (i) {
                i -= 1;
            document.addEventListener(events[i], reset, false);
            }
            reset();
            //end idle if ios found

        }//end of detecting navigator

         }//end of check idle home
/// Code for load new section

var previd='';
function switchVideo(source,id,frame) {
    document.getElementById(id).className='';   
    document.getElementById(frame).src=source;
    if(previd!='' && id!=previd) {
        document.getElementById(previd).className='inactiveVideo';      
    }
    previd=id;

}
```

I want to stop the timeout event when i loaded new tab with this function

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't put your opening curly braces on the next line down in JavaScript, they should go on the same line as the opening function/conditional statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reset() function clears the setTimeout and then starts a new setTimeout. Every time you call reset() you'll have a new setTimeout() so you should have a separated reset function for the last timeout.

```
reset = function () 
                {
                    clearTimeout(timer); // clears the Timeout
                    timer = setTimeout(logout, delay); // Starts a new timeout
                    //alert(timer);
                };

realReset = function ()
                {
                  clearTimeout(timer); //clears the timeout definitely
                }
```

I hope I've been useful.